# How to tell if a file was corrupted through a form-based web page file upload (input type="file")

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, corruption

Is it possible for file corruption to occur during a form-based web page file upload?  I'm talking about when an input of type "file" is submitted as part of a form and a file is saved somewhere on the server (usually in a server-app-defined temporary upload directory).  If corruption is possible during this transfer, is there any way to tell without knowing a file's checksum before performing the upload and confirming that the checksum has not changed after the upload?

We all upload files to various sites on a regular basis without calculating checksums in advance.  If there isn't some kind of check, are we risking corruption every time?

Comment: With the ever increasing use of HTML5 you could use the FileAPI and a javascript md5 checksum function to compare with the server's version once the file is uploaded. Not the best check because data can easily be spoofed but it's one basic way. Also not all browsers support the FileAPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be any corruption: TCP (HTTP's underlying transport) has built-in message integrity checking using checksums. Yes, there is a very small chance of a corrupted message having a correct checksum , but this is generally not worth going out-of-your-way to identify and correct. According to this paper ( http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=347561&dl=GUIDE&coll=GUIDE ) the odds of a corrupted packet being delivered are between 1-in-16 million to 1-in-10 billion packets. Most packets are about 1.4KB (due to Ethernet's MTU), so if your average uploaded file is 1MB then the risk of each 1MB upload being corrupted is between 1-in-2800 or 1-in-1.7million. That's quite a range, and the 1-in-2800 figure certainly gives me pause-for-thought, but it's your call.

TCP ensures that the packet will be resent if the recipient's network stack detects a corruption, this is transparent to the application using TCP, especially your browser-based application.

You could use HTTPS for greater message integrity security, by the way.